# How can I set the page template of a new custom post type post?

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

I'd like to pre-define page_template choice in the page attributes when creating a new post in a custom post type.

Found lots to do with adding parents defaults, but stuck getting past that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the template files within your theme using the correct naming.

Please see:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-page-templates-for-specific-post-types

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear - I want the template auto selected when I add a new post / page / custom post type.

So under page attributes, my client doesn't have to keep selecting page template and selecting the custom template from the drop down box.

Comment: Please take a look at: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204657/apply-template-to-custom-post-type

Answer (score 1):

It's in the filename. single-$posttype.php, archive-$posttype.php

Comment: maybe I wasn't too clear - I want the custom template, using the newer method of template identification that heady12 references above, auto selected when I click new page (or new custom post type)

Comment: How many different templates do you need per post type (foo)? If it's one, call it single-foo.php, if it's more than one call the default single-foo.php and use the Template Post Type header in the others.

Answer (score 0):

As heady12 pointed out

[Apply template to custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204657/apply-template-to-custom-post-type)

With some modifications to conditions this worked.